# How does Batman link Lau with the mob?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight

During the proposed joint venture between Lau Security Investments and Wayne Enterprises in *The Dark Knight*, Lucius Fox begins to suspect that LSI's revenue stream is largely "off the books, maybe even illegal." Bruce Wayne later echoes Fox's suspicions.

So, we know that Bruce/Batman suspects something is up with Lau's finances, but how/when exactly does he link that with Lau being the mob's private banker? I don't remember it being explicitly stated in the film. Is it just one of those things we're supposed to accept, or I am I missing something?

Comment: World's greatest detective.

Comment: Lau takes the mob's money -> this probably gets leaked to the police -> Batman + Dent + Gordon hold meeting; Dent says that Lau is gone -> 1 + 1 = ... There's no need to detail all of the various steps, since this is a very believable chain of events.

Comment: "Because I'm Batman!"

Answer (score 1):

It's established that Gordon and Batman are flipping corrupt cops to work for them, making double agents: its explained that before the action of *The Dark Knight* takes place, Gordon has been giving these corrupt cops lightly irradiated bills to buy drugs off the Mob (clearly in large quantities).

This establishes 3 things:

1. The Cops are working for Gordon (how else could Gordon be sure the irradiated bills were used for specific gang related drug purchases?)
2. The Corrupt cops were already known to the mob, and known to be corrupt (the mob wouldn't be doing large scale drug deals with people they didn't trust)
3. **Most Importantly**: Both the police and the mob are compromised with moles and leaks.

At the [Mob Summit](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Mob_Summit), Lau tells the mob that the same corrupt Cops and DEA agents that are working for Gordon tipped off Lau and Maroni that their banks were about to be raided.

Basically:

### Leaks go both ways.